# SQL SELECT a value when it exists, otherwise populate a null value, multiple times

Tags: sql, select, case

I want to select two values that are tied to a table and if they don't exist, populate a null value. But, I only want one row for each record. If I run the query below, the CASE statements create duplicate rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT YT.TITLE, YT.DETAILS,
CASE WHEN XT.ACOLUMN = 'CATEGORY' THEN XT.BCOLUMN END AS CATEGORY,
CASE WHEN XT.ACOLUMN = 'DIVISION' THEN XT.BCOLUMN END AS DIVISION 
FROM DB.YTABLE YT
LEFT OUTER JOIN DB.XTABLE XT
ON YT.ID_NUM = XT.ID_NUM
```

**Data I want:**

> TitleExample1, DetailsExample1, Category1, Division1
>
> TitleExample2, DetailsExample2, null, Division2

**Data I am getting:**

> TitleExample1, DetailsExample1, Category1, null
>
> TitleExample1, DetailsExample1, null, Division1
>
> TitleExample1, DetailsExample1, null, null
>
> TitleExample2, DetailsExample2, null, Division2
>
> TitleExample2, DetailsExample2, null, null

I also tried doing a join using multiple table identities for the same table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT YT.TITLE, YT.DETAILS, XT1.BCOLUMN AS CATEGORY1, 
       XT2.BCOLUMN AS DIVISION 
LEFT OUTER JOIN DB.XTABLE XT1
ON YT.ID_NUM = XT.ID_NUM
LEFT OUTER JOIN DB.XTABLE XT2
ON YT.ID_NUM = XT.ID_NUM
 WHERE XT1.ACOLUMN = 'CATEGORY' AND
 XT2.ACOLUMN = 'DIVISION'
```

This works well if both category and division values are populated. But, if a title and details record does not have an associated category or division, the query will not select the record.

**Data I want:**

> TitleExample1, DetailsExample1, Category1, Division1
>
> TitleExample2, DetailsExample2, null, Division2

**Data I am getting:**

> TitleExample1, DetailsExample1, Category1, Division1

Comment: will be usefull if you post the contant of your table, if you get 3 line for the same title, it's because you have at least 3 lines which match in you XTABLE. Moreover you can't get this result:TitleExample1, DetailsExample1, Category1, Division1, with the first query, because XT.ACOLUMN can't be equal to CATEGORY and to DIVISION at the same time

Answer (score 1):

your second approach is better, but you must add your condition in the ON statement of the OUTER JOIN

```
SELECT DISTINCT YT.TITLE, YT.DETAILS, XT1.BCOLUMN AS CATEGORY1, XT2.BCOLUMN AS DIVISION 
FROM DB.YTABLE YT
LEFT OUTER JOIN DB.XTABLE XT1 ON (YT.ID_NUM = XT1.ID_NUM AND XT1.ACOLUMN = 'CATEGORY')
LEFT OUTER JOIN DB.XTABLE XT2 ON (YT.ID_NUM = XT2.ID_NUM AND XT2.ACOLUMN = 'DIVISION')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just tried out adding the additional condition to the outer join and that worked. G Mastros - I didn't have time to try your solution, but will on Monday. Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT YT.TITLE, YT.DETAILS,
Min(CASE WHEN XT.ACOLUMN = 'CATEGORY' THEN XT.BCOLUMN END) AS CATEGORY,
Min(CASE WHEN XT.ACOLUMN = 'DIVISION' THEN XT.BCOLUMN END) AS DIVISION 
FROM DB.YTABLE YT
LEFT OUTER JOIN DB.XTABLE XT
ON YT.ID_NUM = XT.ID_NUM
Group By YT.TITLE, YT.DETAILS
```